# Swift displayed firebase photoUrl cannot replace image by image picker

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase as the back-end of my app. When user finish authentication they will go to profile create page. It displays the user profile picture from facebook.

I use this code to display

```
func displayProfilePic(user: FIRUser?){

let photoURL = user?.photoURL
struct last {
  static var photoURL: NSURL? = nil
}
last.photoURL = photoURL;  // to prevent earlier image overwrites later one.
if let photoURL = photoURL {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    let data = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: photoURL)
    if let data = data {
      let image = UIImage.init(data: data)
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if (photoURL == last.photoURL) {
          self.profilePic.image = image
        }
      })
    }
  })
} else {
  profilePic.image = UIImage.init(named: "DefaultPic")
}
```

**However**, I also let user to pick their own profile picture by camera or photo library. When user choose their Image it will display the picked Image for 1 to 2 second, and display back the facebook profile picture. **That's mean, the "picked image cannot replace the facebook profile picture"**

It is my code for the camera and photo library

```
func openGallary(){

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
  print("Pick Photo")

  self.imagePicker.delegate = self
  self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
  self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
  self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

func openCamera(){
if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
  self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
  self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
  self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}else{
  print("you got no camara")
}
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

})
profilePic.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication takes a photo **URL**, so the public location where a profile photo for the user is present. If you want to allow the user to upload a new profile photo, you will have to find a place to store the photo and then put the URL into the Firebase Authentication profile.

One place to keep such a profile picture would be Firebase Storage. See the documentation on [how to upload an image from iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) and then [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url) that you store in the user profile.

Comment: Hi @Frank ,  I understand what you mean but my problem is the imageview cannot replace/display a new image when the "photoUrl" image is there. I don't think I need replace the "photoUrl" every time user had pick there profile pic. I am sorry if I didn't make my question my clear.

Comment: or do i need to use "changeRequest" to change the photoUrl everytime user had pick a new photo. Before that I thought I can do all the submission when user had press the upload button(upload to firebase)